# g++/MSYS64/Mingw64/VS Code compilation problems

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, g++, mingw-w64, msys2

When using the g++ compiler in VS Code using the MSYS64 using g++ 12.1.0 I can compile a basic hello world program, but as soon as I introduce code with a vector and I imagine other standard C++ libs, the program compiles however, output is blank. If I go to a past build of g++/MSYS64/Mingw64 builds (g++ 10.3.0) standard libs work, I get output from vectors using cout. I wonder if anyone else has this problem and how to fix it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;
    string test = "test String, test vector"; 
    // if I comment out vector related code output works with cout

    vector<string> testVec(2);

    testVec.at(0) = test;
    testVec.at(1) = test;

    
    cout << testVec.at(0) << testVec.at(1) << endl;

    vector<string> msg{"Hello", "C++", "World", "from", "VS Code", "and the C++ extension!"};

    for (const string &word : msg)
    {
        cout << word << " ";
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Try running your compiled program from the mingw64 shell. Also try flushing the output stream

Comment: A classical .dll issue. Double-click the app in the explorer to observe an error message. Add `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin` as the *first* entry in the *system-wide* PATH to fix.

Comment: So I do have C:\msys64\mingw64\bin in both the system and local path. g++ works only when I use an older path of msys64 to my tasks.json file. GDB only works when I use the new path...

Comment: It appears to work in the mingw64 shell.